# Variable creation to increment to pass object to object of my object (not find on forum) JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a variable which can be incremented which will allow me to pass in the objects of my object to display them 1 to 1 to each clique (example P1 => P2, P2 => P3 ect .. so on

```
This.question = {p1: {…}, p2: {…}, p3: {…}, p4: {…}, p5: {…}, …} (etc)
```

my code for the moment :

```
var affichePage = this.questionnaire.Profil;
      for(var question in this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"]){
        this.current=this.questionnaire.Profil["p2"][question];
        console.log(question, " -> " + this.questionnaire.Profil);
        break;
}`
```

Comment: so you are trying to add attributes to your `question` object?

Comment: no I want that when I'm on my page (with default p1 (already done)) when I click on next I get to the next element (for example it's p2) and I want each click I go to the next item hiding the previous one each time but i do not know how to do it: /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var This = {};
This.question = { p1: { a: "p1" }, p2: { a: "p2" }, p3: { a: "p3" }, p4: { a: "p4" }, p5: { a: "p5" } };

for (var question in This.question) {
  if (This.question.hasOwnProperty(question)) {
    console.log(question + " -> " + This.question[question].a);
  }
}
```

If I understood what you asked correctly this snippet would help to solve your problem.Just change "a" property based on your requirements.

Comment: yes, you understand; but I can not take it back

`This.question = {p1: {a:" p1 "}, p2: {a:" p2 "}, p3: {a:" p3 "}, p4: {a:" p4 "}, p5: {a : "p5"}}; `

because I do not know how many PX there are; and that's 13 topic group (with different question number)